# Sending files in client - server in C++ using scket API

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, client-server

I am doing client and server that is able to send and receive files. But I can't really find any useful function that I can use to serve my purpose.

In client I tell the server which file to download and on which port and on the server I tell the port and limit on download speed in kB/s. I know how to do the connecting and stuff around it, but I really don't know how to choose the file, how to send it and how to receive it + how to set the speed limit on download. (I should use socket API and TCP protocol)

Comment: For opening and reading from a file, look at the `ifstream` class and related. You probably will read from the file into a buffer, and from the buffer to the socket. You cannot really control the download rate from the server, but you can approximate it by the rate at which you put bytes into the socket

Comment: I guess I can normally open the file, read some number of bytes and then send them using send() and recv(). But How I can aproximate the speed rate? Maybe using usleep() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a something from where you can start.

Server

```
/*Receive File from Client */
#define LENGTH 512
    char* fr_name = "/file.jpg";
    FILE *fr = fopen( fr_name, "wb");
    if( fr == NULL)
        printf("File %s Cannot be opened file on server.\n", fr_name);
    else
    {
        bzero( revbuf, LENGTH); 
        int fr_block_sz = 0;

        bpt::ptime start, stop;
        start = bpt::microsec_clock::local_time();
        int totalBytes = 0;
        double transferRate = 0.0;

        while((fr_block_sz = recv( nsockfd, revbuf, LENGTH, 0)) > 0) 
        {
            stop = bpt::microsec_clock::local_time();
            bpt::time_duration dur = stop - start;
            double seconds = dur.total_milliseconds() / 1000.0;
            totalBytes += fr_block_sz;
            transferRate = totalBytes / seconds; // b/s

            int write_sz = fwrite( revbuf, sizeof(char), fr_block_sz, fr);
            if( write_sz < fr_block_sz)
            {
                error( "File write failed on server.\n");
            }
            bzero( revbuf, LENGTH);
            if ( fr_block_sz == 0 || fr_block_sz != 512) 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(fr_block_sz < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EAGAIN)
            {
                printf("recv() timed out.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "recv() failed due to errno = %d\n", errno);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        printf("Ok received from client!\n");
        fclose(fr); 
    }
```

Client

```
FILE *fs = fopen(fs_name, "rb");
    if(fs == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: File %s not found.\n", fs_name);
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero(sdbuf, LENGTH); 
    int fs_block_sz;

    bpt::ptime start, stop;
    start = bpt::microsec_clock::local_time();
    int totalBytes = 0;
    double transferRate = 0.0;

    while((fs_block_sz = fread(sdbuf, sizeof(char), LENGTH, fs)) > 0)
    {
        if(send(sockfd, sdbuf, fs_block_sz, 0) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to send file %s. (errno = %d)\n", fs_name, errno);
            break;
        }
        stop = bpt::microsec_clock::local_time();
        bpt::time_duration dur = stop - start;
        double seconds = dur.total_milliseconds() / 1000.0;
        totalBytes += fs_block_sz;
        transferRate = totalBytes / seconds; // b/s

        bzero(sdbuf, LENGTH);
    }
```

Instead of boost you can use standard utilities from `<time.h>`

```
#include <time.h>
time_t start,end;
time (&start);
.
.
.
<your code>
.
.
.
time (&end);
double dif = difftime (end,start);
printf ("Elasped time is %.2lf seconds.", dif );
```

Comment: Why there is a check on fr_block_sz != 512? And is this handling the download speed?

Comment: + why u use  bzero over memset? Is there any advance in that?

Comment: bzero is more efficient due to the fact that is only ever going to be zeroing memory, so it doesn't have to do any additional checking that memset may do

Comment: however you should use memset if code has to be standard, bzero is deprecated

Comment: the check is because #define LENGTH 512

Comment: Is There a way how to find out how long a file is being send? so I can use usleep for the rest of the seccond to limit the download speed?

Comment: sure, send a length before the file bytes

Comment: Don't really understand what u mean now. For example if the speed is set to 10000 kB/s what length should I send and what will be the result?

Comment: You asked if there is a way to know the file length before the download starts. Yes, you can send a file length as integer before the actual file bytes.

Comment: Oh I ment if there is a way how long the sending of LENGTH number of bytes will take.

Comment: I guess I can use gettimeofday before and after the send and then do some math.

Comment: @Whitedracke added meassuring speed. There is no way to find how long the sending of file will take in advance. You can estimate but this will be a singing of fairy tales...